# Posting multiple images in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, mobile

So, the general problem I am confronting is that I cannot select multiple images BEFORE I post them . I have created a function called pickImages in a separate file, which looks like this :

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

Future<List<Uint8List>> pickImages(ImageSource source) async {
  final ImagePicker _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  final List<XFile>? _files = await _imagePicker.pickMultiImage();

  // Initialize an empty list of Uint8List to store the image data
  List<Uint8List> images = [];

  // Check if the user selected any files
  if (_files != null) {
    // Loop through all selected files
    for (XFile file in _files) {
      // Read each file as bytes and add to the images list
      Uint8List imageData = await file.readAsBytes();
      images.add(imageData);
    }
  } else {
    print("No images selected");
  }

  // Return the list of image data
  return images;
}
```

and I implemented that to my add_post.dart screen, and my whole code looks like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:uridachi/utils/utils.dart';


class AddPost extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddPost({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddPost> createState() => _AddPostState();
}

class _AddPostState extends State<AddPost> {

  List<Uint8List>? _files;

  _selectImage(BuildContext context) async {
  // Show dialog to choose the image
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text("Choose your image"),
        children: [
          SimpleDialogOption(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const Text('Select a photo'),
            onPressed: () async {
              // Close the dialog
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              // Call pickImages to get the list of selected images
              List<Uint8List> images = await pickImages(ImageSource.gallery);
              // Update the state with the new images
              setState(() {
                _files = images;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text("Add Post"),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text(
                "Post",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  //post details
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 32, // Adjust the radius to fit your design
                    backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 182, 182, 182), 
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                      color: Colors.white,
                        size: 64, // Adjust the size of the icon as needed
                    ),
                  ),
          

                  const Divider(),
          
                 
                ],
              ),
          
               SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
          
          
          
          
               Container(
                 child: Column(
                   children: [
                     SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Write your content..",
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                            ),
                            maxLines: 8,
                          ),
                        ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
          
          
             
          
          
              Column(
                children: [
          
                  Center(
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.upload),
                      onPressed: () => _selectImage(context),
                    ),
                  ),
          
                  
           SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
          
                  


                  
                   Container(
  height: 100, // Set a fixed height for the container
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // Use the full width of the screen
  child: _files != null && _files!.isNotEmpty
      ? ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // For a horizontal list
          itemCount: _files?.length ?? 0, // Safely handle the itemCount
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Image.memory(_files![index], fit: BoxFit.cover); // Display each image safely
          },
        )
      : Center(child: Text("No images selected")), // Show a message or an empty container if no images are selected
),



          
          
               
          
          
          
          
          
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see, I have defined :

```
List<Uint8List>? _files;

  _selectImage(BuildContext context) async {
  // Show dialog to choose the image
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        title: const Text("Choose your image"),
        children: [
          SimpleDialogOption(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: const Text('Select a photo'),
            onPressed: () async {
              // Close the dialog
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              // Call pickImages to get the list of selected images
              List<Uint8List> images = await pickImages(ImageSource.gallery);
              // Update the state with the new images
              setState(() {
                _files = images;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

these two guys in the _AddPostState, and I am trying to display the images inside a Container as a Listview on the bottom of the page so that the users can check what they are posting. However, I am keep getting the "null check operator" errors where I know I need to deal with it using '?' or '!', but I don't know what to do here. What should I do so that I don't get the null error and get to see all the images the user is trying to post?

I tried to deal with the null error I have been facing in the ListView, but I cannot solve it. In addition, I only see one photo coming up inside the ListView.

Comment: Without seeing the actual error it's unclear, but you're being nasty there with popping the context and then using setState().
If you need it to be a DIalog for this, move the pickImage() + setState() calls into a method and call it after popping.